# how to convert data string into multiple column names

Tags: r, dataframe

Thanks in advance for your help.  I have a few thousand lines and need to normalize so I can run an analysis.
Data structure -

> row 1 - {'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'POL', 'document_type':
>   'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-07-21',
>   'issuing_country': 'POL'}
>
> row 2 - {'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'LTU', 'document_type':
>   'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2023-06-27',
>   'issuing_country': 'LTU'}
>
> row 3 {'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry':
>   '2044-12-14', 'issuing_country': 'GRC'}
>
> row 4 {'gender': 'Male', 'document_type': 'driving_licence',
>   'date_of_expiry': '2024-08-05', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}

I would like to have 
(1) Gender as col name and Male or Female as value
(2) Nationality as col name
(3) Document_type as col name 
(4) Date of expiry as col name 
(5) issuing country as col name

Pls note each raw may or may not have all the element.

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: Please use dput(), so we could help you

Comment: Please read this on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us what you have tried, where do you get stuck. And please indicate where the is coming from. Is it a json string, or a source system that delivers the data like this?

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume you have a few thousand lines like this:

```
{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'POL', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-07-21', 'issuing_country': 'POL'}
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'LTU', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2023-06-27', 'issuing_country': 'LTU'}
{'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2044-12-14', 'issuing_country': 'GRC'}
{'gender': 'Male', 'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-08-05', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}
```

That is invalid regular JSON, invalid nsjdon and invalid javascript object syntax.

One way to deal with it is to turn it into valid ndjson by replacing single quotes with double quotes:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ndjson)
library(stringi)

readLines(textConnection("{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'POL', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-07-21', 'issuing_country': 'POL'}
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'LTU', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2023-06-27', 'issuing_country': 'LTU'}
{'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2044-12-14', 'issuing_country': 'GRC'}
{'gender': 'Male', 'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-08-05', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}")) %>% 
  stri_replace_all_regex("([^\\\\])'", '$1"') %>% # replace non-escaped single quotes with double quotes
  ndjson::flatten("tbl") # turn the character vector of now valid
## # A tibble: 4 x 5
##   date_of_expiry document_type         gender issuing_country nationality
##   <chr>          <chr>                 <chr>  <chr>           <chr>      
## 1 2024-07-21     national_identity_ca… Male   POL             POL        
## 2 2023-06-27     national_identity_ca… Female LTU             LTU        
## 3 2044-12-14     driving_licence       NA     GRC             NA         
## 4 2024-08-05     driving_licence       Male   GBR             NA
```

An alternate way is to use the `V8` package since — in javascript land — we can use `eval()` which (for whatever reason) is less picky about the way javascript objects are specified:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(V8)

ctx <- v8()

readLines(textConnection("{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'POL', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-07-21', 'issuing_country': 'POL'}
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'LTU', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2023-06-27', 'issuing_country': 'LTU'}
{'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2044-12-14', 'issuing_country': 'GRC'}
{'gender': 'Male', 'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-08-05', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}")) %>% 
  lapply(function(line) {
    ctx$eval(sprintf("var line = eval('(' + \"%s\" +')');", line))
    ctx$get("line")
  }) %>% 
  data.table::rbindlist(fill=TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
##   gender nationality          document_type date_of_expiry issuing_country
## 1   Male         POL national_identity_card     2024-07-21             POL
## 2 Female         LTU national_identity_card     2023-06-27             LTU
## 3   <NA>        <NA>        driving_licence     2044-12-14             GRC
## 4   Male        <NA>        driving_licence     2024-08-05             GBR
```

Both are fragile ops since we don't know anything about your data. i.e. Is there a chance of escaped single quotes? Is there the chance of embedded double quotes? Is this the format your data is in?

Note that V8 is hard to get running on some systems but please don't post comments about that if it fails to install on your system as it's out of scope for the answer.